# ORA-28040 No Matching authentication protocol when connecting from SQL PLUS to oracle 12c DB using sql plus client version 11.1

Tags: oracle, authentication, protocols

I am getting ORA-28040 when trying to connect oracle 12c remote database from sqlplus while able to connect successfully when connecting to same same database using SQL developer(both basic and TNS connection). Also I have noticed that I am able to connect to 12c database from sql plus which are on local network but this problem is only with regards to remote database server

I have already tried below settings in client sqlnet.ora file

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you are trying to use an unsupported combination of client and server. The actual error is raised as 12c is using a new password encryption algorithm. Setting SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER in the client sqlnet.ora file cannot work. The error is caused by the server side. Therefore the sqlnet.ora file of the server needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I guess another option is to update the client version of sqlplus to 12 ? I am using SQL developer version 17.3 which is supported combination of client and server and due to which I am able to make connection from SQL developer. But still I am unable to understand why I am able to connect to 12c database which is local development environment connected via LAN from same sqlplus version ?

Comment: Yes, updating the client to 12c will also work. It is possible that SQL developer and sqlplus use a different version of the sql client.