# Error connecting to 19c Database "No Matching protocol"

Tags: java, oracle

We had upgraded from Oracle 11g to 19c recently and one of the Java program which connects to Oracle DB via OJDBC started throwing below error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)

We have tried the below options :

1. Added the below lines in sqlnet.ora
   `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8`
   `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8`
2. Replaced *ojdbc14.jar* with *ojdbc6.jar*.
3. Other JARs that I tried are *ojdbc7.jar* , *ojdbc8-full.jar*.

None of the above seems to work. When I tried replacing with *ojdbc8-full.jar*, I get to see a different error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> DB_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)...

Oracle Version: 19c
Java Version: 1.7

Comment: Why don't you use the [thin style service name syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-EF07727C-50AB-4DCE-8EDC-57F0927FF61A) for the URL?

Comment: Please check this post if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843189/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-when-connecting-from-sql-plus-to-o

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, maybe he needs features like failover which are not possible with thin style

Comment: Have you restarted the listener after the sqlnet.ora changes? I've never found full documentation on this, but I know from experience that some parameters require restarting the listener and some even require restarting the database.

Comment: I have not restarted , I will try that . Thanks!